# Getting data within range date, but broken down by each day, with a single query in SQL

Tags: python, sql, group-by

I have a table that logs session activities from the users. These are the fields: id | name | category | total_steps | created_at | training_id | user_id (fk) | completed_at

I want to display a chart in my frontend that will show the activity per day for all users like in this picture:

[image]

My backend uses Python and SQL and I'm using MySQL as database. I came up with the sql query like this:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as total_logins,
SUM(TIMEDIFF(completed_at,created_at)) as total_time_spent 
from metrics_session 
where created_at >= '2021-04-01' 
AND created_at <= '2021-04-02'
AND completed_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id
```

which for a table with the following data:
[image]

it would give me a result like this:

[image]

which is correct, however as you can see these would not give me the details break down by each day. I would like a result like this:

[image]

*(just fictitious values that might not be in accordance to the data present in table, but the point is, when you sum up all the total_logins and total_time_spent it should be the same amount as given by the previous picture with the results. Only difference is the range of dates being break down by each day)*

so the solution I initially came up was to call this query looping for each day, and just changing the date parameters used in this part

```
where created_at >= '2021-04-01' 
AND created_at <= '2021-04-02'
```

Obviously that is not efficient as it would require the same query to be called 30 times for a monthly activity, so I decided it's better to do that manipulation in Python and just have a single simple query selecting all the data from the full range. However I want to improve my SQL skills and I was wondering if there is any way I can do that within SQL?

Comment: Could you please specify the desired output, then? It isn't clear what you are expecting the query to return. On the other hand, it'd help to know which RDBMS you're using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the date in order to get all the points you want to paint, and stop to group by `user_id`, to get the full picture without grouping by users

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
  count(user_id) as total_logins,
  sum(TIMEDIFF(completed_at,created_at)) as total_time_spent 
from metrics_session 
where created_at >= '2021-04-01' 
  AND created_at <= '2021-04-02'
  AND completed_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you wanted to show this chart to single users, you could add to the query the `user_id` as another filter in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
  count(user_id) as total_logins,
  sum(TIMEDIFF(completed_at,created_at)) as total_time_spent 
from metrics_session 
where created_at >= '2021-04-01' 
  AND created_at <= '2021-04-02'
  AND completed_at IS NOT NULL
  AND user_id = $your_user_id -- here for user view
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. yes, your answer is correct for the chart I'd like to display. However, this wouldn't give me the details by each user, just all them together. yes, my bad, I forgot to mention that I was curious to see a solution for that scenario as well when I would like to know by user and days

Comment: Hi, I completed the answer with just what you are asking for

Comment: ah I see, yes...why didn't I think of that? Haha, thanks for taking me out of the box!

Comment: another question. Why was the date(created_at) casting necessary for this query? Indeed if I remove that it does not work

Comment: I didn't know your RDBMS system, so I used `date` as a function to extract just the date from the `created_at` datetime attribute. If you are using MySQL, you need to change the `date(created_at)` by, for example  `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: I have updated the queries with the changes. Is the answer is valid, please mark it as correct.